# How to display rows data in multiple column using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I  am trying to display some student score data in a single row  as per subject If  student UID is same. Please suggest me is it possible in a single Mysql query or I need to use php conditions for that. Here is my table after collecting the informations.

```
     sl |   uid         | name      |   subject |   score
 ---------------------------------------------------------
     1  |   a1          |  AA       |   Math    |  80
     2  |   b1          |  BB       |   Math    |  78
     3  |   a1          |  AA       |   Physics |  70
     4  |   b1          |  BB       |   Physics |  67
```

I want to display like this  all score as per subject wise in a single row.

```
  uid           | name      |   math    |   physics
---------------------------------------------------
  a1            | AA        |   80      |   78
  b1            | BB        |   70      |   67
```

Here is my code  and it is giving me the out put in different row. Please help me to sort out this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.uid, a.name,a.subject,a.score from STUDENT a, STUDENT b where a.uid=b.uid AND a.std=b.std GROUP BY a.uid, a.subject
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use some sort of pivot mechanism; see, for example,
[MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)